# how to divide pyspark recipe dataframe into chunks in dataiku?

Tags: python, pyspark, dataiku

i have a managed file system where there are 7 million records.
i have to get max value for one of the column of date.

```
import pyspark
import dataiku
from dataiku import spark as dkuspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

some_table = dataiku.Dataset("some_table")
df = dkuspark.get_dataframe(sqlContext, some_table)
**df.select('date').unique().collect()**
```

this above highlighted line takes lot of memory to run.

can i run it on RDD pyspark?

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh* that not everyone understands.